# How to pass an object into a state using UI-router?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'd like to be able to transition to a state and a pass an arbitrary object using ui-router.

I'm aware that usually `$stateParams` is used, but I believe this value is inserted into the URL, and I don't want users to be able to bookmark this data.

I'd like to do something like this.

```
$state.transitionTo('newState', {myObj: {foo: 'bar'}});

function myCtrl($stateParams) {
   console.log($stateParams.myObj); // -> {foo: 'bar'}
};
```

Is there a way to do this without encoding values into the URL?

Comment: ui-router mechanisms preserve URL states across navigation.
Thus, if an user refreshes the page, he comes back to the page he was in.
If you don't want to use this behaviour, consider using other mecanisms (raw functions in your controller/directives, etc), and use cookies/storage for storing temporary data

Comment: Use localStorage with the url as the key for your data maybe?

Comment: Where do the values come from? Ui.router has the concept of a "resolve" to load data onto a scope before transitioning to the requested state. Similarly there are onEnter and onExit methods. In addition, you could use local storage.

Comment: As @JoshC. mentioned, sounds like you may want to look into resolving data before moving to a state. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve

Comment: See stackOverlord's answer as how to do it officially.

Answer (score 164, accepted):

In version 0.2.13, You should be able to pass objects into $state.go,

```
$state.go('myState', {myParam: {some: 'thing'}})

$stateProvider.state('myState', {
                url: '/myState/{myParam:json}',
                params: {myParam: null}, ...
```

and then access the parameter in your controller.

```
$stateParams.myParam //should be {some: 'thing'}
```

myParam will not show up in the URL.

Source:

See the comment by christopherthielen https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/983, reproduced here for convenience:

> christopherthielen: Yes, this should be working now in 0.2.13.
>
> .state('foo', {    url: '/foo/:param1?param2',   params: { param3:
>   null } // null is the default value });
>
> $state.go('foo', { param1: 'bar', param2: 'baz', param3: { id: 35,
>   name: 'what' } });
>
> $stateParams in 'foo' is now { param1: 'bar', param2: 'baz', param3: {
>   id: 35, name: 'what' } }
>
> url is /foo/bar?param2=baz.

Comment: Works with `transitionTo` as well.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong :-/ I'm on 0.2.13 but if I attempt to pass and object it comes out the in the state as the string `[object Object]`

Comment: @ErichBSchulz Though it's not included in this answer, the trick to making this work is including the parameter name in the state's URL string and specifying the type as JSON. ex. `$stateProvider.state('myState', { url: '/myState/{myParam:json}', params: {myParam: null},...` See the [0.2.13 release notes](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/releases/tag/0.2.13) and the code comments for this feature.

Comment: I had an id param in my URL and had to add that to the params object as well. `{ url: '/mystate/{id:[0-9]+}', params: { id: null, myParam: null }, ...`

Comment: Somebody needs to buy @Syon a beer!

Comment: There must be some black magic at play - my whole json is showing the the  url :(((

Comment: @stackOverlord its working fine but the data that im passing in myParam is showing in the url too! which i dont want.

Answer (score 25):

There are two parts of this problem

1) using a parameter that would not alter an url (using params property):

```
$stateProvider
    .state('login', {
        params: [
            'toStateName',
            'toParamsJson'
        ],
        templateUrl: 'partials/login/Login.html'
    })
```

2) passing an object as parameter:
Well, there is no [direct way how to do it now,](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/400) as every parameter is converted to string (**EDIT**: since 0.2.13, this is no longer true - you can use objects directly), but you can workaround it by creating the string on your own

```
toParamsJson = JSON.stringify(toStateParams);
```

and in target controller deserialize the object again

```
originalParams = JSON.parse($stateParams.toParamsJson);
```

Comment: Actually for passing objects this is quite a nice hack :)

Comment: we can pass object directly. check the accepted answer

Answer (score 21):

Actually you can do this.

```
$state.go("state-name", {param-name: param-value}, {location: false, inherit: false});
```

[This is the official documentation about options in state.go](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stategoto--toparams--options)

Everything is described there and as you can see this is the way to be done.

Comment: I tried this exact code and the object is not preserved.

Comment: you can't pass objects you can only pass single parameter values.... yo make it as an object you must put all of the properties as different url parameters. Angular-ui-router devs are still working on passing whole object. Actually that guys Svatopluk Ledl gave a nice solution. Just make the object as a whole json string and after that parse it. :)

Answer (score 13):

Btw you can also use the ui-sref attribute in your templates to pass objects

```
ui-sref="myState({ myParam: myObject })"
```

Comment: How do we receive this object in .state

Comment: @Shubham you would configure the 'params' for the state which will receive the object, then using $stateParams to retrieve that object. see the doc http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider for detail.

Comment: this works but cannot keeping the data after page refreshing.

Answer (score 9):

1)

```
$stateProvider
        .state('app.example1', {
                url: '/example',
                views: {
                    'menuContent': {
                        templateUrl: 'templates/example.html',
                        controller: 'ExampleCtrl'
                    }
                }
            })
            .state('app.example2', {
                url: '/example2/:object',
                views: {
                    'menuContent': {
                        templateUrl: 'templates/example2.html',
                        controller: 'Example2Ctrl'
                    }
                }
            })
```

2)

```
.controller('ExampleCtrl', function ($state, $scope, UserService) {


        $scope.goExample2 = function (obj) {

            $state.go("app.example2", {object: JSON.stringify(obj)});
        }

    })
    .controller('Example2Ctrl', function ($state, $scope, $stateParams) {

        console.log(JSON.parse($state.params.object));


    })
```

Answer (score 3):

No, the URL will always be updated when params are passed to `transitionTo`.

This happens on [state.js:698](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/master/src/state.js#L698) in [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router).