# On Clicking Search Button, i need to display result page in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a text box with a search Button  as below

On clicking the search button, I am calling SearchController.search method and 
my expectation is it will display a new page with the result.

```
$scope.search = function () {
     $http.get('data/results.json').success(function (data) {
        $scope.activities = data;
        $state.go('results',data);
});
```

and my app.js looks as below

```
var myApp = angular.module('MyApp', ['ui.router']);
myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
     .state('results', {
         url: '/results',
         templateUrl: 'result.html',
         controller: 'SearchController'
      });
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
});
```

But when I click on search button, nothing happens and url only changes to l/#/results .

I am not having any ui-view in search page and I want to go results page to display the result. How to get this fixed? what is the mistake I am doing?

Comment: Hmmm, it has to do with the format of the data you're passing to the $stateParams of the result page. I'm not sure if you can pass an object to the params like that. Can you give a hint/more info about the "data"?
However, that's not how to pass query to routes in angularJs

Comment: data is json formatted data. it is basically search result . so if i am searching for names of people, then data would look like  [{name:vinaya},{name:general}]

Comment: If the object was to be returning just a single value, I would have suggested you pass it in as a query params with "?name" like 
`$state.go("result", {name: data.name});` and your state url like `url:'/results?name'` and everything will be fine. but it's different.

Answer (score 1):

You can't send a not mapped object into $state.go.

Looking the API: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state

Another similar problem: [AngularJS: Pass an object into a state using ui-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20632255/angularjs-pass-an-object-into-a-state-using-ui-router)

Comment: what would be a ideal solution  , if i  want search results to be displayed on a  different page ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display it on a different page, use the "ui-sref" on the html to navigate to the new page and call ng-init on the page e.g

```
<button type="button" ui-sref="results">
```

and on result.html, you can call the init on the parent node such as

`<section ng-init="search()">
  .....
  ....
</section>`
and your controller will look like this now

```
$scope.search = function () {
  $http.get('data/results.json').success(function (data) {
    $scope.activities = data;
});
```

Comment: How can i pass the input search box value?

Comment: I guess you want to display the data with respect to search input? if so, write a filter on the ng-repeat that display the data. 
But if you strictly want to display that alone, you can also use lodash to findWhere the data correspond and then display them.

Answer (score 0):

With ui-router, state changes happens and different view is displayed based on state. So , when ui-router is used , moving from one page to another page is a wrong perception .  We move from one state to another state  and hence parameter passing can be done using "services".