# $state.go doesn't pass parameters

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

This is the part of my HTML:

```
<td>
   <button class="btn btn-primary" ui-sref="edit({id: v.customerId})" ui-sref-opts="{reload: true}">Edit</button>
   <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="removeRow(v.firstName);">Delete</button>
</td>
```

as you can see I am passing the `customerId` as and `id` to be one of the parameters displayed in the url

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('webtrekkApp', ['ngSanitize', 'ui.router']);
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('edit', {
            name: 'edit',
            url: '/users/:id/edit',
            templateUrl: './views/customer-details.html',
            controller: 'ctrl',
            params: {
                obj: null
            }
        });
});
```

ctrl.js:

```
//If 'initData' isn't set, then set it up by default
    if(!localStorage.getItem('initData')) {
        $window.localStorage.setItem('initData', JSON.stringify($scope.initData));
    }
    $scope.retrievedData = JSON.parse($window.localStorage.getItem('initData'));
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.retrievedData.length; i++) {
        $scope.retrievedData[i].birthdayDate = new Date().getFullYear() - new Date($scope.retrievedData[i].birthdayDate).getFullYear();
    }
    $scope.sortedType = 'firstName';
    $scope.sortedReverse = false;
    //Remove Rows and Update localStorage Key Values
    $scope.removeRow = function(name) {
        var index = $scope.retrievedData.findIndex(function(obj) {return obj.firstName === name});
        $scope.retrievedData.splice(index, 1);
        window.localStorage.setItem('initData', JSON.stringify($scope.retrievedData));
    };
    $state.go('edit', {obj: $scope.retrievedData});
```

So I a table, and when users clicks on 'edit', I need `THAT object` to be passed to the ui.router so I can display it in `customer-details.html`. How can I do it? I am doing something wrong here. I have read all the documentation on ui.router but do not know should `$state.go` be defined in the initial controller or in some other. Also I've followed this question, but couldn't get it to work: [How to pass custom data in $state.go() in angular-ui-router?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30165272/how-to-pass-custom-data-in-state-go-in-angular-ui-router)

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19516771/how-to-send-and-retrieve-parameters-using-state-go-toparams-and-stateparams

Comment: ` params: { 'obj': null }` Have you tried adding the parameter like this in the app.config->state.

Comment: This is the message I receive: `angular-ui-router.min.js:9 Error: Param values not valid for state 'edit'`

Comment: is $scope.retrievedData populated before calling the $state.go() ?

Comment: Yes.. but this is all in one controller, could that be an issue?

Answer (score 2):

In your edit state you have two parameters, `id` and `obj`, one of which inside the url.

But when you trigger the state from your controller you are not passing the id parameter and you did not define a default value

```
$state.go('edit', {obj: $scope.retrievedData});
```

try adding it inside your params object

```
params: {
   obj: null,
   id: null
}
```

EDIT:

to answer your further question:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="handleItem(v);">Go to Edit state</button>

$scope.handleItem = function(item){
 //here extract your item specific data from $scope.retrievedData then change the state
 var itemData = getItemData(item, $scope.retrieveData);
 $state.go('edit', {obj: itemData});
}
```

Comment: But isn't the id passed in the html in ui-sref?

Comment: sorry, you were right. I get the object passed, but now I pass the entire object, while I need to pass only the property that is clicked so I can interpolate it in my view.

Comment: I get the object passed in console: `Object {#: null, id: "2", obj: Array(5)}` but I need to pass only the one that is clicked.

Comment: it's not clear from the code when you trigger that $state.go,  anyway wrap your $state.go inside a method and trigger it onclick on the button passing the information of which item has been clicked

Comment: That's what I should do,  probably with ng-click? But how can I pass the information of that particular item, that's what's bugging me..

Comment: are you still here?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you are not using controller, if you want to pass parameters to $state.go() you should have controller to get that value in particular state.

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('webtrekkApp', ['ngSanitize', 'ui.router']);
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('edit', {
            name: 'edit',
            url: '/users/:id/edit',
            templateUrl: './views/customer-details.html',
            controller: 'myController',
            params: {
                obj: null
            }
        });
});
```

in Controller

```
function myController($state) {
   conrole.log($state.params.obj);
}
```

Comment: I'm still receiving this error:  `angular-ui-router.min.js:9 Error: Param values not valid for state 'edit'` Should `$state.go()` be defined in my initial controller, where my index.html is, or some other, where my view is?

Comment: yes you are right, keep 'conrole.log($state.params.obj);' in your initial controller. I have given just example