# Angular uiRouter open state in new window or tab with stateParams

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

What I want to do is following in but in a new Tab or new Window:

```
$state.go('studentsReport', {
       type: $scope.report.type, // string
       selectedStudents: $scope.selectedStudents // array of strings
});
```

If I did:

```
var link = $state.href('studentsReport', {
       type: $scope.report.type,
       selectedStudents: $scope.selectedStudents
});

window.open(link, '_blank');`
```

I would lose the parameters.

Best regards,
Marcel

Answer (score 5):

You should trying to use this:

```
/* @ngInject */
function SomeCtrl ($state, $window) {
  $window.open($state.href('stateName', {}, {absolute: true}), '_blank');
}
```

Note: the `/* ngInject */` facilitates automatic dependency injection annotation if using ng-annotate (available in [cli](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate), [gulp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-ng-annotate/), and [grunt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-ng-annotate) flavours)

Comment: Thanks for you reply, but this does not work. But I have to say, I did not use the comment /* @ngInject */, assuming it's just a comment

Comment: @molerat I have to say, i did not set params in second argument of [$state.href](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state) function. You should trying to set their.

Comment: I know, I set them their and it did not work. What url should `$state.href('stateName', {test: 'bla'}, {absolute: true}) ` return if we say the normal url would be http://localhost/stateName ?

Comment: @molerat don't fully get your question. You can configure your url just as you need to: [URL-Routing](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing). Maybe you should trying to read this answer: [angularjs-pass-an-object-into-a-state-using-ui-router](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20632255/angularjs-pass-an-object-into-a-state-using-ui-router)

Comment: @molerat in my case url should be equal `localhost/#/stateName/bla` :)

Comment: Okay Philipp, I'm sorry. I edited my question to make it more clear. Please take a look at it again

Comment: No, I ended up using GET-params in the url

Answer (score 0):

use ng-click on link tag and call a function. in function put your parameters in LocalStorage. then in app.run use $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart") and check if localstorage have parameters get params and call $state with params.

```js
//in page controller: 
var openNewTab = function () {                  
                    localStorage.newTab = JSON.stringify({
                        state: "yourState",
                        params: {
                            param1: "someparam1",
                          param2:"someparam2"
                        }
                    });                  
                    window.open(document.location.origin);
                      
                }
 
 //angular app run config: 
angularApp.run(function($state){
if(localStorage.newTab){
   var newTab = JSON.parse(localStorage.newTab);
   localStorage.removeItem("newTab");
   $state.go(newTab.state, newTab.params);
   event.preventDefault();
}
})
```

```html
<a ng-click="openNewTab()" >open new tab</a>
```