# Passing multiple parameters to state in the path

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have this state definition:

```
         .state("workPlan.list", {
             url: "MainPage",
             templateUrl: "app/workPlan/templates/workPlanList.tmpl.html",
             controller: "workPlanListController",
             controllerAs: "list",
             resolve: {
                 workPlans: ["workPlanServise", workPlanServiseResolver],
                 inspectionAuthority: ["lookupService", inspectionAuthorityResolver],
                 clients: ["lookupService", ClientsResolver]
             }
         })
```

The current path is:

```
/cities#/MainPage
```

I need to pass in URL some data:

```
 'Table':'Clients'
 'Key':'Name'
 'Value':'ClientId'

 'Table':'Dates'
 'Key':'Desc'
 'Value':'DateId'

 'Table':'Sites'
 'Key':'SiteName'
 'Value':'SiteId'
```

I need to send the data above in URL path:

```
/cities#/MainPage?{'Table':'Clients','Key':'Name','Value':'ClientId'}{...}{...}
```

then in state definition I need to use it in resolve function.

So my question is it possible to send the data in the path in format above and how can I access it in resolves function.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can do it, everything is in the documentation: [ui-router github wiki](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing)

You will define your state URL with parameters (double colon - e.g. ":table"), and use `$stateParams` service in `resolve` function:

```
$stateProvider
.state('contacts.detail', {
    url: "/MainPage/:table/:key/:value",
    templateUrl: "app/workPlan/templates/workPlanList.tmpl.html",
    controller: "workPlanListController",
    controllerAs: "list",
    resolve: {
        data: ['$stateParams', function($stateParams) {
            console.log($stateParams.table);
        }]
    }
})
```

The parameters will be also available in state controller if you inject `$stateParams` service.

Comment: is it possible to send it as JSON?

Comment: You can pass stateParams in `ui-sref` as javascript object, so no, I don't think you can. However, you could convert the JSON to string and escape it as necessary... http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref

Comment: but you can go to a state and pass object inside javascript - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20632255/angularjs-pass-an-object-into-a-state-using-ui-router

Answer (score 2):

calling your state

```
 $state.go('stateName', {test_one: 'para1',test_two: para2, test_three:'para3'});
```

or

```
 window.location.href = 
 this.$state.href('stateName',
 {test_one: 'para1',test_two: para2, test_three:'para3'});
```

routes.js where you define your state.

```
 $stateProvider
    .state({
      name: 'stateName',
      url: '/test/?test_one&test_two&test_three',
      views: {
        'content@portal-layout': {
          controller: Controller,
          template: require('./test.html')
        },
      }
    })
```

finally your url look like this

```
 https://test/?test_one=para1&test_two=para2&test_three=para3
```