# Avoid declaring query params in ui-router URLs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, query-string

I'm using `ui-router` project to handle my web-app navigations. In my screens I have input widgets (like date-picker and selectors) which change the query parameters in the url. In order to do so I declare the state as follows:

```
angular.module('my.project', ['ui.router', 'ngMaterial'])
  .config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {
      $stateProvider
          .state('page', {
             url: '/page?customerid%from%to',
             // rest of state definition
      })});
```

Then, when things change on screen, I use `$state.go()`. For example, if the *from* widget changes I call `$state.go('.', {from: fromwidget.text})` which changes the url.

Thing is, I have a lot of parameters that can change and I feel it's a bit redundant to define each of these params in the `url` section of the `state` definition. I would like to just declare the base-url, in my case `url: '/page'` and when I call `$state.go()` to change the `$stateParams` and just use them in my controller. I don't have any need to know in advance the exact parameters that are allowed to be passed to the state

Comment: Not really sure if you can do that with $stateParams, maybe just define the state with the base path and use $location to get the parameters ?

Comment: @Walfrat - Thanks for your comment. Thing it, if I don't define the parameters in the state, I can't use `$state.go()` to change the url. And I do want to use this, just don't want to define the params in advance :)

Comment: you may find this answer helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26021346/2460773