# how to pass data through hyperlink using angular routing

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

Html Code

```
 <div ng-init="initAppliedJob()" style="padding:25px;" >
 <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ApplicantID</th>
            <th>Username</th>                
            <th>Edit</th>           
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="obj in initAppliedJobObj">
            <td>{{obj.ApplicantID}}</td>
            <td>{{obj.Username}}</td>        
            <td><a href="/admin/home/appliedlist/:{{obj.loginid}}">Edit</a></td>               
        </tr>
    </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

Angular Route

```
app.config([
'$locationProvider', '$routeProvider',
function ($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
    }).hashPrefix('!');

    $routeProvider
          .when('/admin/home/appliedlist', { 
        templateUrl: '/AngularTemplates/jobAppliedList.html',
        controller: 'JobApplyController'
    })
    .when('/admin/home/appliedlist/:userid1', { 
        templateUrl: '/AngularTemplates/jobAppliedList1.html',
        controller: 'JobApplyController'
    })
    .otherwise({   // This is when any route not matched => error
        templateUrl: '/AngularTemplates/help.html',
        controller: 'JobApplyController'
    })
}]);
```

Controller

```
 app.controller('JobApplyController', function ($scope, appliedJobService, $routeParams) {

alert($routeParams.userid1);    
$scope.initAppliedJob = function () {
    var getData = appliedJobService.initAppliedJob();
    getData.then(function (emp) { $scope.initAppliedJobObj = emp.data; },
    function (response) { document.write(response.status + "<br/>" + response.data); });
}
});
```

I am using angular routing when I click on Edit button my hyperlink shows like
       http://localhost:1395/admin/home/appliedlist/:14

And in Controller I am getting value in alert box  ":14"

Question:

1) I want value only 14 not :14 because every time I have to split that value to get original value
2) And My router goes to otherwise part that means not detect this part
   .when('/admin/home/appliedlist/:userid1'

how to solve this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove the `:` from your `href` attribute and use `ng-href` instead, ie `ng-href="/admin/home/appliedlist/{{obj.loginid}}"`

Comment: I think instead of `href` you should use `data-ui-sref`.

Comment: @ojuskulkarni the `ui-sref` directive belongs to `ui.router`. OP is using `ngRoute`

Comment: @Phil right he is using `ngRoute`. so we cannot use ui-sref

Comment: thanks  @Phil  right  i used ng-href  . i got my first solution . what problem in my second part

Comment: Check out this thread. Should answer your queries. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20632255/angularjs-pass-an-object-into-a-state-using-ui-router

Answer (score 0):

change

```
 href="/admin/home/appliedlist/:{{obj.loginid}}
```

to

```
href="#/admin/home/appliedlist/{{obj.loginid}}
```