# Pass object to a new page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have some json which is being ng-repeated:

```
{
"title": "image title",
"description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, per ea ferri platonem voluptaria, ea eum ubique ornatus interpretaris. Dolore erroribus reprimique ex mea, mei soluta iisque cu, cu eam repudiare iracundia. Te cum populo molestie noluisse. Cu graece propriae eum, at qui erat oportere, ad wisi consequat persecuti pri. Ne usu partem discere, quas aliquam id cum. Tation numquam sensibus pri ne, his cibo noluisse scriptorem in.",
"imageUrl": "http://some.url.com",
"tags": "Apple, Orange, Banana, Pear, Grapes, Peach",
"owner": "some name",
"thumbnailUrl": "http://some.url.com"
},
```

On the index page it only shows the thumbnailUrl, if you click on the image it should pass that object to a new 'page'/template and display the description/author etc.

I've tried using various examples and none of which seem to work as I want. Quite confused and any help would be awesome.

Comment: Have you considered/tried using a service to share data across different pages ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using some sort of router, you can pass this object to the new page, or like code90 said, you can use a service to maintain these objects between pages.

EDIT: Here is a link to the ui-router page

https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router

Comment: I'm using ngRoute if that helps

Comment: change to use ui-router, it is more fully featured.  Then you can use $state.go("stateNmae", param) when the image is clicked, where "stateName" is the name of the state you wish to go to, and the param object would be the object you wish to pass

Comment: You don't happen to have a quick and dirty example by any chance? Fairly new to Angular and I'm still getting my head around it all. Cheers.

Comment: This page should provide some color: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20632255/angularjs-pass-an-object-into-a-state-using-ui-router