# Handle dynamic set of query string parameters with UI Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Let's say I have a url that has an exploded object as its query string parameters: "domain.com/example?id=1234&params[a]=hello&params[b]=world&params[foo]=bar //etc etc etc"

How do I configure angular ui-router to accept this dynamic set of query string params?

```
.state('example', {
    url: '/example?id&params[*]' ??
    ...
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Here, it seems your `params` is an associative array.

You can see on this link https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/983
comment of christopherthielen

```
.state('foo', { 
  url: '/foo/:param1?param2',
  params: { param3: null } // null is the default value
});
$state.go('foo', { param1: 'bar', param2: 'baz', param3: { id: 35, name: 'what' } });
$stateParams in 'foo' is now { param1: 'bar', param2: 'baz', param3: { id: 35, name: 'what' } }
```

And also according to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/29792020/1907391

In version 0.2.13, You should be able to pass objects into $state.go,

```
$state.go('myState', {myParam: {some: 'thing'}})

$stateProvider.state('myState', {
                url: '/myState/{myParam:json}',
                params: {myParam: null}, ...
and then access the parameter in your controller.

$stateParams.myParam;
```